# How i can make the php code reach an url and an path

Tags: php, html, function, url, path

I'm trying to make a php|html code which will do the following things
First i have an input when we submit our urls 
And when we submit an url like "example.com" i will have an array which has some path names

```
name1.php
name2.php
```

And if that files exist on that domain the output is going to be true if not false.
I am really struggling with the connecting part i don't know how to connect to the paths and if that exist to be true the response. 
I searched everywhere but i didn't find anything related on this.
Thanks!

Comment: Honestly?  I don't understand a thing of what you are trying to do.

Comment: need more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the basic of what you need.

First, I am giving the code then I will give the helpful links.

```
<html>
<form method="post">
<input type="url" name="url" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$file = $_POST['url']; //The link submitted
$file_headers = @get_headers($file); //We retrieve the headers of the link
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    //If the header above(which indicates the page doesn't exist) returns true we will show this
    $exists = "The page Does not Exist";
}
else {
    //If returns true we gonna show this
    $exists = "The Page Exists";
}
echo $exists;

}
?>
</html>
```

I think this is the basic thing you need. You told you want to search for some files stored in an array. You can easily do that using this code by putting the page names after the link like this:

```
$file = $_POST['url'];
$finalurl = $_POST['url']."name1.php";
```

Know more about get_headers in PHP [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

[Working Demo](https://lishup.com/anthony.php)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much appreciate for your help !